# Telerik RadAsyncUpload

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using a RadAsyncUpload to upload a file to the server and it works fine unless I decide to have multiple tabs open that will each be uploading different files for different tabs then it seems the each RadAsyncUpload steps on each other because one RadAsyncUpload steps on another in the ASP.Net Temp folder. Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

you can use many AsyncUploads, which upload many files. Probably you hit some validation due to file upload limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the multiple file selection in RadAsyncUpload which will prevent the need to upload different files in different tabs: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/multiplefileselection/defaultcs.aspx
All you need to do is setting the MultipleFileSelection="Automatic" property.